# Hyperledger business logic

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have defined following business network in IBM Hyperledger Composer

========================================

```
  namespace org.india.invoicefinance

enum InvoiceState {
  o SUBMITTED
  o APPROVED
  o REJECTED
  o FINANCED
}

asset InvoiceLedger  identified by invoiceNumber {

    o String invoiceNumber
    o DateTime invoiceDt
    o Double amount
    o Integer creditPeriod
    o String poNumber
    o InvoiceState invoiceStatus
    --> Buyer buyer
    --> Seller seller
}
participant Buyer identified by buyerId {
    o String buyerId
    o String orgName
    o String contactName
}

participant Seller identified by sellerId {
    o String sellerId
    o String orgName
    o String contactName
}

transaction Invoice {
    o String invoiceNumber
    o DateTime invoiceDt
    o Double amount
    o Integer creditPeriod
    o String poNumber

  --> Buyer buyer
  --> Seller seller 
}
========================================
```

During transaction processing function, I would like to perform following validations:

Buyer is present in Buyers, Seller is present in Sellers, invoicenumber is not present in invoiceledger

Can anyone help or guide me to achieve this?

Thanks a lot...
Umesh

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the smart contract here for comparative operators -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/animaltracking-network/lib/model.cto.js that you can check out

Note if you pass in a reference to your Buyer, Seller and invoiceNumber (all of which could be relationships in transaction `Invoice`, based on your model) then you would have the CURRENT Buyer, seller and Invoicenumber in question. Obviously, you can connect to those individual registries, to check other records (as you allude to). Example of lookups here -> (simpler model, with transaction having multiple relationships) https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/tree/master/packages/trade-network/models  (more complex model) https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/perishable-network/models/perishable.cto and txn logic  -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/perishable-network/lib/logic.js